# Spring Cloud Contract with Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-contract

Does Spring Cloud Contract support Spring Kafka message contract verification out of the box?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Spring Cloud Stream with a Kafka binder then yes it should work out of the box. Where out of the box means that either you can have the infra completely stubbed out (via the test binder) or you can connect to a real kafka instance and send real messages to it.

Comment: I'm not using SCS just plain Spring Kafka. In that case how do I go about using Spring Cloud Contract?

Comment: Ah so in that case you have to check our spring cloud contract spring amqp module and do sth similar. Messaging contract verifier module contains interfaces to send and receive messages. If you register those as beans then it should work without issues

Comment: why not using the Schema registry? While working with apache Kafka it is better to use the Schema Registry which has more advantages than only validating the contracts.

Comment: schema validates the semantics, contracts validate both semantics and usage

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples) is a repo with examples of using spring-cloud-contract with messaging (stated under the [producer](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples#producer) section) which should apply to Kafka as well.

https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples

The example .groovy file with the contract is located [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer/src/test/resources/contracts/beer/messaging/shouldSendAcceptedVerification.groovy).